# NSFileManager creating folders herarichy & not saving plist [open]

Tags: ios, plist, nsfilemanager, nsdocumentdirectory

The problem is appearing on device not on simulator.

```
 NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Plist1.plist"]; 

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSLog(@"documentsDirectory  --- %@", documentsDirectory);
    NSLog(@"path --- %@", path);
    @try
    {
        if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path])
        {
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:documentsDirectory toPath:path error:&error];
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@" [exception description] -- %@", [exception description]);
    }
    @finally {

    }

    [dictEmot writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

    // To verify
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSLog(@"[dict allKeys] My plist ----- %@", [dict allKeys]);
```

Above is the code which I have written to save two plist files in my documents directory. same method I use to save my second plist.

```
[self savePlist:plist1];
[self savePlist:plist2];
```

My problem is whenever I try to save second plist it creates hierarchy of folders inside documents directory and also not saves my plist2 file with it contents.

once it complets the 2nd method call, my app documents directory looks like below,

```
Documents
 -> plist1
   -> plist1
      .
      .
      .
     -> plist1
       -> plist1
other files
```

I treid doing on main thread also but same result.

its not even printing exception.

- What is my mistake ?

  ### - Why its creating hierarchy ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about iOS but I think your problem is with `stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Plist1.plist"` Check your documentation as I am supscious by the word Appending and even if you send new file name as you are hardcoding the value of the filename to Plist1.plist...

Still I am not sure as I have not done iOS coding for a long time now.